# How to prevent Angular2 core making dozens of HTTP requests on page load?

Tags: javascript, angular

So I'm developing an Angular2 application, and just by bootstrapping Angular2, I'm sent over 250 requests for nearly every js file present in the `@angular/core` node module package:

[image]

Specifically, everything seems to be imported from `zone.js:101`. Here is my application entry point, just to demonstrate I'm not doing anything unusual:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { LiveComponent } from './components/live.component';

bootstrap(LiveComponent);
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
       defaultJSExtensions: true
    });
    System.import('js/angular2/main').catch(function(err){ console.error(err);  });
</script>
```

And here is `systemjs.config.js`:

```
(function(global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
        'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };

    var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/router-deprecated',
        '@angular/testing',
        '@angular/upgrade',
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    }

    // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
    if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That setup is for development only. 
For production, you should create a bundle.
SystemJS has the [SystemJS Builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder).

[JSPM](http://jspm.io/docs/production-workflows.html) will give you more options.

EDIT to answer your comment:

Yes, it's a build step. This [seed](https://github.com/madhukard/angular2-jspm-seed) project uses gulp, TypeScript, TSLint, SystemJS and JSPM to build the front end.
It has distinct gulp configurations for the development build and [production](https://github.com/madhukard/angular2-jspm-seed/blob/master/tools/gulp/tasks/production/scripts.js) build.

Also, in that seed project you'll see that the [package.json](https://github.com/madhukard/angular2-jspm-seed/blob/master/package.json) *dependencies* section is empty. That is because he uses JSPM ([this config](https://github.com/madhukard/angular2-jspm-seed/blob/master/app/jspm-config/config.js)) to manage the dependencies.

Now the bundler will follow the `import {} from 'dependency'`s used by you code and only add to the bundle what was really used.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail? This is a pre-processing step correct? I.e. it'd get included in something like a gulp task?

Answer (score 1):

There is new systemjs config in official quickstart
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Here is the copy

```
// Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });
```

So we can use their UMD bundle, and I tried it, from ~400 requests to about ~60 requests.