# How to bundle Angular2 RC1 with systemjs

Tags: angular, bundle, rxjs, systemjs

Prior to the release candidates angular supplied a bundled file.  Since the release candidates there's no more bundled file.  Including angular2 and rxjs my app now makes 671 requests over 7secs to load.  This has crippled development.

Does anyone know how to bundle angular and rxjs and include these in system.config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get a lighter weight project you should check [SystemJS Builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder) or [JSPM](http://jspm.io/docs/production-workflows.html) to bundle your project.

Example seed project: https://github.com/madhukard/angular2-jspm-seed

@BrunoGarcia gave a very nice info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37098964/5706293

Answer (score 7):

You just need to use a bundler:

- **UMD files:** it's probably the easiest solution. As you can see in this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6qKhdlpauky7D8DGWLpx?p=info). You just need to make a reference to the UMD files in your systemjs config file (not so useful for production enviroments):

  ```
  System.config({
      packages: {
          app: {
              main: './main.ts',
              defaultExtension: 'ts'
          },
          '@angular/core': {
              main: 'core.umd.js',
              defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          '@angular/compiler': {
              main: 'compiler.umd.js',
              defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          '@angular/common': {
              main: 'common.umd.js',
              defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {
              main: 'platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
              defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          '@angular/platform-browser': {
              main: 'platform-browser.umd.js',
              defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          rxjs: {
              defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
      }
  });
  ```

  You can find another exampe (probably better) [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8717#issuecomment-220359530)!
- **systemjs-builder + gulp:** if you wanna keep using systemjs, it's a good call to use this solution, however I've tested it and it took me 30s to generate the bundle, making it not so useful for development (maybe I was doing something wrong [almost sure]), but you still can check how to bundle your application using system-builder [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37082199/1292016);
- **webpack:**  I'm currently using webpack. Webpack has a dev tool called webpack-dev-server that bundle the application virtually on the memory making the process faster during development (+ hot reload). You can find a quick [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9w5hFit5rM) here and a more detailed description from Angular 2 documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html). In order to use webpack you must install webpack (and webpack-dev-server if you want to) packages: `npm i -S webpack webpack-dev-server`, create a *webpack.config.js* file and run it using only `webpack` to just generate the bundle file or `webpack-dev-server --inline` to create a server that aut re-bundle with your modifications. The --inline option enables auto reload on the browser window:

  ```
  // webpack.config.js file
  module.exports = {
      entry: 'SRC_DIR/main.js',
      output: {
          path: 'BUILD_DIR',
          filename: 'bundle.js'
      }
  }
  ```

  Now insert your bundle.js file on your index.html: `<script src="BUILD_DIR/bundle.js"></script>`

These two last options will allow you to generate a bundle of the whole application that you can manually include in your index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

1)con-cat all js files  and css files include on index.html using  `gulp-concat`.

2)Bundling angular libraries and app components mentioned in `systemjs.config.js` file. Using gulp  `systemjs-builder`.

3)Minify bundles  using `gulp-uglify`.