# Transform angular2 app from local NodeJS one to a website

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular 2 - I just finished the official Tour Of Heroes tutorial (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) and built my own website with weather just for training.

The whole application from the tutorial was built using NodeJS, which, as I understand it, is used to run javascript files.
But, what if I want to upload my website to a server (one of the free hostings) to see how it looks like on my other devices (mobile, tablet, etc.)?

Without angular, I wouldn't have problems with that - I'd just use FTP client to upload my .html, .css and .js files to the hosting.
But how should I do it with angular2 application? In my project's directory there are folders like: node_modules, typings - they contain a lot of files, and I'm not sure if they are needed. I know that browsers do not support TypeScript (which I'm using), so I should only upload .js files, but how exactly should it be? Which files should I upload?

I tried uploading everything but node_modules and typings folders, but I just got "Loading..." when I tried accessing the website.

I saw this: [Hosting Angular 2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786319/hosting-angular-2-app)
and there people just said to upload every js file, which I did.

Here's the link to my website: http://myweatherapp.comxa.com

**//EDIT
All the above can be represented by this one question: What are the steps to transform local angular2-quick-start-app into a website, which can be uploaded to any web-hosting?**

Comment: One way is you can use **webpack** along with **babel** to bundle and transpile the code into one JS, like index.js.

Then you will only have to upload your views and css and index.js file to the server.

Comment: I'd rather like to upload my website without implementing new packages to it. isn't that possible?

Comment: OK, so is there any guide (I can't find it), which would show me the steps to transform my local nodeJS angular 2 app (like quickstart app from angular2 tutorial) into a website, which I could just upload to a hosting? I'm new to all this stuff and I don't really know how to do it. Another thing: when I'm running my app with NodeJS, i have tsconfig.json, and there is target: "es5" - isn't that enough to get js files, that internet browsers would understand?

Comment: check this out hope it clears your doubt http://stackoverflow.com/a/35563542/2680461

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [**Angular-Cli**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

They make it so easy to build/bundle Angular 2 apps. They include a `ng build` and `ng build:prod` commands to build the angular 2 project into a distribution folder, standalone web app, so you can put it in a tomcat instance or anywhere and not just in a NodeJS environment.

Angular-Cli provides everything one could want when building an Angular 2 app.
Take a look at their [**Table of Contents**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#table-of-contents). The [**Build**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#creating-a-build) section is probably what you are more interested in

I use Angular-Cli and I absolutely love it.

Comment: I'll check this out tomorrow and will tell how it went

Comment: @Loreno Cool! Good luck!