# Angular 2 Web Pack 404 Html Template Urls

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server

I'm using Angular2 RC4 version and webpack dev server. I'm not able to successfully load my application. On the browser console it throws 404 and fails to load AppComponent template file using webpack. This works if I use lite-server

app.component.ts snippet

```
@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'body',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
```

webpack.config.js snippet

```
 module:{
       loaders:[
            {test:/\.ts$/, loader:'ts',   exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test:/\.html$/, loader:'html' },
       ],

    },
```

**Error**
browser_adapter.js?0526:84Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load /app.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Angular2 webpack,

Use template like this-

```
  template: require('./app.component.html'),
  styles: [require('./app.component.css')]
```

instead of

```
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it and it is working. However, there are more issues working with web pack. How do we bundle and deploy Angular 2 app using SystemJS?

Comment: How would npm run bundle work? We have to explicitly configure it. Can you explain?

Comment: Refer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/angular-2-how-to-bundle-for-production-currently-rc3

Comment: this is actually an antipattern according to https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter `Don’t use require statements for your templates or styles, use styleUrls and templateUrls, the angular2-template-loader plugin will change it to require at build time.` so with the correct configurations you don't need require..

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use awesome-typescript-loader in combination with angular2-template-loader to inline all your styles for you, and you don't need require.

https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: This approach worked best for me. It is worth noting, though, that you also need to make sure you have an appropriate loader for HTML/CSS files, such as the `raw-loader` suggested in the GitHub link.