# angularjs 2: SecurityError: Failed to execute

Tags: angular

I tried to run angularjs 2 app dist files as simple html page. i.e. I just double click index.html in the dist folder. But the app is not working: Error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute
>   'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL
>   'file:///D:/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and
>   URL 'file:///D:/dev/ProxyVoting/ngapp/dist/index.html'.

Comment: You can't just click on index.html and except it to work. Your page needs some mandatory files that are not accessible without using a server (Apache, node.js, ...).

Comment: @mickdev can you be descriptive about what kind of files the page needs? Thanks.

Comment: See here for more detail about Angular 2 App production : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38765929/7447071

Answer (score 2):

**First Step:**

Run the command

```
ng build
```

or

```
ng build -prod (then it will compact all files for production version)
```

**Second Step:**

Change at index.html in dist directory

```
<base href="/"> to <base href="./">
```

**Third Step:**

Put all files into server(may be htdocs in localhost or any server)

Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 1):

use an ***HTTP server instead of direct file access***. I was facing the same problem; So, I used XAMPP & got it working.

So, your **`index.html`** would contain `base href` something like this - `<base href="http://localhost:81/etl/">`

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTP protocol instead of file transfer protocol. For that open build in http server. I'm using node server

```
npm install http-server -g

cd path/folder

http-server
```

Answer (score 1):

why not something like that?

```
history.replaceState = (data:any, title:string, url?:string) => {;//nothing};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I got it working completely in a fairly complex angular 2 app with multiple nested routes.

All I needed was

Router configuration with
`CommonModule,RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash:true})`

Of course you need to import CommonModule first
`import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';`

and this in the index.html file
Removed base Href="/" tag from html and added it like this.
`<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Running the `dist` folder on actual web server solved my issue.