# Angular2-cli not considered app folder files and some other files in dist folder.

Tags: angular, angular2-build

I have used below steps to generate dist in production

```
npm install -g angular2-cli
ng new PROJECT_NAME
cd PROJECT_NAME
```

After this I have copied all the code it included app folder

```
ng serve
```

it will open my project and runs successfully.

```
ng build --prod
```

Now it is building everything and creating dist folder also, but incomplete. There is no app folder or required files.

Please suggest me the method to generate angular 2 build. I want to host this build in any web server.

Answer (score 0):

app folder only for development, when build process complete you got all files you need to deploy on a sever, not app, not src.

Comment: True that.. I mean it has not considered app folder files. If I run the dist in webserver I am getting error saying that files are missing. Because I have included some node module and script or css files in index.html.

Comment: change your `base` tag or serve your app at root like this, `myapp.com` for example. if you serve your app at  `myapp.com/subapp` , just change base to something like this `<base href="../">`

Comment: The problem is assets folder is not created inside the dist.  And its <base href="../"> only

Answer (score 0):

### Output of build

- `dist/main.[hash].bundle.js` Your application bundled [ size: 13 KB for new Angular CLI application empty, **~3 KB** compressed].
- `dist/vendor.[hash].bundle.js` Your dependencies (@angular, RxJS...) bundled [ size: 440 KB for new Angular CLI application empty, **99 KB** compressed].
- `dist/index.html` entry point of your application.
- `dist/inline.[hash].bundle.js` webpack loader
- `dist/style.[hash].bundle.css` the style definitions
- `dist/assets`resources copied from `projectFolder/src/assets`

Referred from:
[How to bundle an Angular app for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/how-to-bundle-an-angular-2-app-for-production)

Comment: True that.. I mean it has not considered app folder files. If I run the dist in webserver I am getting error saying that files are missing. Because I have included some node module and script or css files in index.html. In fact all those files where created. If I host those files in web server it showing error. And assets folder is missing inside

Comment: I better understood now what is your problem. You have to install the third party library with angular cli (see the documentation https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation)