# Angular2 build only showing app works

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I got an Angular 2 app which im ready to build and host on a webserver. I followed [How to bundle an Angular app for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/how-to-bundle-an-angular-2-app-for-production) to build my app.

I have uploaded all the files in the dist folder to my webserver but when opening the URL I dont see my app. I only see "app works!".

Im assuming I need to edit some config to point to the correct paths but I dont know where to start with this as its the 1st time building an Angular2 app.

My project files:

[image: Project Structure]

Files on webserver:

[image: Webserver]

Navigating to my webserver I see app works! and not the home page screen.

Please help

Comment: you need to change its default route for component, otherwise its perfectl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it seems your base path on the web server doesn't match `<base/>` tag in your `index.html`.

You can change it manually or via a param - follow the guide on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml).