# how to speed .net Core angular 2 component loading

Tags: angular, angularjs-components

i had created a application and in my master page i have initialize my app 
like this

```
<my-app>
 Loading...
</my-app>
```

here is the way im loading my component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '/App/my.Component.html'

})
```

in my component i have only HTML template

when my page is load i can visible the "Loading..."  text before loading the component

how can i speed up the component loading time ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/how-to-bundle-an-angular-2-app-for-production/38765929#38765929 development mode is much slower than when built for deployment.

Comment: but i have activate the enableProdMode()

Comment: That's only a tiny part. How many files does the browser load when you load your application?

Comment: yes it loading too much files

Comment: That's because it's not built yet.