# Bundling an Angular 2 application in a subfolder of an ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2 application in a subfolder of an ASP.NET project, and would like to bundle the Angular 2 application using the techniques from [How to bundle an Angular app for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/how-to-bundle-an-angular-2-app-for-production)

The recommended approach there is to set up a project using Angular CLI. However I am having some trouble using that approach since it makes some assumptions about the project structure.

Assuming that the Angular 2 application is located in the subfolder `/Angular2App/` it seems Angular CLI would like the `index.html` to be located in `/Angular2App/src/`, and when bundling the result is located in `/Angular2App/dist/` and all references there from that folder's `index.html` assume that bundles are located at `/`.

However I would simply like the Angular 2 application to be available at `/Angular2App/`.

Any ideas as to how I can configure Angular CLI in this way?

Comment: in the angular-cli.json file you have the settings like "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": ["assets"],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "scss/style.scss"
      ], ..try to change there

Answer (score 3):

You should set `deployUrl` when you build your angular application and then all path variables will have prefix `/Angular2App/`. For example;

```
ng build --deployUrl "/Angular2App/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `base-href` flag to set a base url other than the root.

```
ng build --base-href=/Angular2App/
```

From the Angular docs:

> If you copy the files into a server sub-folder, append the build flag,
>   --base-href and set the  appropriately.
>
> For example, if the index.html is on the server at /my/app/index.html,
>   set the base href to  like this.
>
> ng build --base-href=/my/app/
>
> You'll see that the  is set properly in the generated
>   dist/index.html.

https://angular.io/guide/deployment