# Angular 4 min js file size

Tags: angular, vue.js, filesize

What is the .min.js file size of Angular4 (or just Angular now) ? I can't find any information about this.

I am comparing Vue 2.0 and Angular 4 and its file size is one point of it.

75kb for vue.min.js (v.2.2.6)

622kb for angular2.min.js (v.2.0.0-beta.17) (which is not exactly what I am looking for)

Edit: Since some understood the question wrong: I am not trying to get the smallest possible bundle ! All I am looking for is the size of the vanilla min.js file without any compilers

Comment: You're comparing it wrong. Use a bundler with tree shaking will remove unused code and resulting in much smaller bundle.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi this is not what I am looking for, you read the question wrong, all I want is the size of the min.js file, I have not said anything about getting it as small as possible, just the vanilla min.js

Comment: Then it's more wrong. Angular has many feature modules, and the size highly depends on what feature you use.

Comment: [CDNs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.17) offer the min.js file for 2.0 and I am looking for exactly this file for Angular 4

Answer (score 5):

The minimal size with Angular CLI with prod flag to get a low size (see [How to bundle an Angular app for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/how-to-bundle-an-angular-2-app-for-production/38765929#38765929) for details) is **52 KB**.

You can also use experimental Google Closure Compiler integration with Angular to get a size of **16.6 KB** (see http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/minimal-angular-application and the GitHub issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8550)

Comment: I did not ask for getting a smaller bundle, what's the actual vanilla size of the angular 4 .min.js ?

Comment: There are 3 min files and their total size compressed is 77 KB.

Answer (score 2):

Use ahead-of-time compilation to reduce the size of bundle.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Comment: AOT won't reduce the size of the bundle (actually, it can even increase it, because a small template can be heavier when compiled), tree-shaking will reduce the size.