# Angular 2 minimized War For Deployment

Tags: angular

I come from an Ext JS background, where we can run a build command and then create a war from the minimized source code.

Now I am finding it difficult to do such thing in Angular 2.

How can we minimize the Angular code & then create a WAR for deployment?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimized war for deployment"?

Comment: @edkeveked My bad, I meant minimized.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 comes with CLI commands which you need to use for building & serving your app in different runtime environments. For running it on your local dev machine you can use `ng serve` command.

For building and deploying to production environment you can use `ng build --prod` and then copy the contents from `.dist` directory on the server from where you wish to host your app.

Comment: Thanks Gurdev, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Angular CLI as mentioned in the other answer uses what's called Ahead of Time compilation, which creates a single minified file for the whole Angular app. You can also do this without the CLI. See my earlier answer here:

[How to bundle an Angular app for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/how-to-bundle-an-angular-app-for-production/41642504#41642504)

Comment: Thanks Peter, this was helpful.