# Deploying Angular2 app with NodeJs backend

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment

I am working on a project with UI side made on Angular2, and backend on NodeJs. Currently NodeJs LTE server is used. Is there a way I can deploy the whole project on another server like Apache Tomcat or Websphere or JBoss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can when you are building the angular 2 project , a folder name /dist will be created. if the project is using angular-cli thn run this command `ng build --prod`.
you can put that /dist into any server .

for further details see this thread 
[How to bundle an Angular app for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/how-to-bundle-an-angular-app-for-production)

Comment: could you please let me know how to deploy the /dist into a server. I am new to this, so don't have much idea for the same.

Comment: after build you will have 3-4 main files,
dist/main.bundle.js
dist/vendor.bundle.js
dist/polyfill.[hash].bundle.js the polyfill dependencies (@angular, RxJS...) bundled [ size: 62 KB for new Angular CLI application empty, 18 KB compressed].
dist/index.html entry point of your application.
dist/inline.[hash].bundle.js webpack loader
dist/style.[hash].bundle.css the style definitions
dist/assetsresources copied from the Angular CLI assets configuration
put it into /public if its node , or /www/html if any other server

Comment: Thank you. So I have to copy the files from /dist and put it into the server's folder right?

Comment: Okau, I am using Websphere, but cannot find any folder named like /www/http. Am I look it right?  Or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: I am using NGinx server, so do I have to create a folder inside /html or simply put the bundle files inside that?

Comment: /html will have the index.html in same folder other bundle.js file will resides