# angular2+ can build a release module that does not contain src code?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

for example, I have a project, and it export a module named 'myNgmodule'; other projects can install and import it to use. but as the usual, we can see all the src code in node_modules. so can I build a 'release' version that does not contain the src code for other use it?

and I found a [repo](https://github.com/hansl/AngularSample), the library project seems build a release folder, and be imported into main.app, but I don't know how it works

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to build Angular in production mode, you have to call

```
ng build --prod --no-sourcemap
```

You should also take a look at this documentation about running Angular in production: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production

See also this other question: [How to bundle an Angular app for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/how-to-bundle-an-angular-app-for-production)

Comment: but if i npm publish my repo, and others install it, it still contains source code ?

Comment: AFAIK, yes; one ugly/hacky way to get around that would be to have a separate repository just for publishing the compiled code. Please keep in mind that the compiled code will still be JS; you can use uglify.js or some code obfusctor to make it less readable and more compact, but it will still be JS.

Comment: yeah,  the compiled code will still be JS is ok, as long as it can be imported into another module.  so would you please tell me how to publish the compiled code? thanks

Comment: You would need to create a separate repository; that repository would contain only the compiled code. You would publish your package from that repository, instead from your main one.