# I am using nginx for project deployement and I am using windows

Tags: nginx

Can anyone please help me what changes I have to made in conf nginx.conf.
And after making changes, what commands I have to writeon windows for showing 404 page. I have create an html page for 404 condition.

Answer (score 0):

In your `nginx/sites-available/default` configuration file, you can add the following to your server setup:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    error_page 404 /your_custom_404_page.html;
}
```

Comment: For deploying, do we need something other than nginx or it's nginx is enough

Comment: For a static website, nginx is more than enough.

Comment: I have to deploy an angular application only

Comment: You need to build your application into an HTML/JS bundle I believe.

Comment: I am not getting what you are asking....are you asking about my directory structure of my angular application

Comment: I am talking about building your angular application.. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/how-to-bundle-an-angular-app-for-production).

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which are too broad. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer