# Run angular and node.js project locally without sharing code

Tags: node.js, angular, starling-server

**Suppose i have a project that i have made in angular and node
Till now for the development purpose i run through NG serve , but definitely i have to show code  , that i don't want .
i want to install locally in customer's PC , not internet connection all work will be done locally .
So how can i achieve this ?**

npm start and ng serve all run by code , i java spring we done this type of work by uploading war file without any source code , same i want here , i want some compress code to run , no user who have the access of the LOCAL PC can not read code , because it's a security breach .

Answer (score 0):

You can build your angular project for the production refer [How to bundle an Angular app for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631098/how-to-bundle-an-angular-app-for-production) and then copy files from the dist to any HTTP server folder.

HTH