# How to decrease size of bundle main.js file using Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

1. Hi, after type npm command "ng build --prod --aot" , main.js file
   2.58MB size .so it cause to initial load page slow.
2. How to decrease size of bundle main.js file size .?
3. I have implemented with using Lazy loading module  (preload), Gulp
   compression and enable Gzip compression.

[image: Dev Console Result]

**gulpfile.js**

```
 var gulp =require('gulp');     //本地安装gulp所用到的地方
     uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
     gulp.task('jsAssets', function () {
     gulp.src('/*.js') //Project Folder
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/')); //same folder minified
   });
 gulp.task('default',['jsAssets']);
```

Comment: ng build --prod and practice lazy loading through the router. Where necessary, you can also make use of TypeScript dynamic imports e.g. within functions.

Comment: Use the below link, this might helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38765929/7896998

Comment: @user2644848  I have used var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'); for all js file minified.